# Why am I getting "non -option ARGV element: XXXX" in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to make a file for login into cyberoam client in Linux.

crclient is a file which takes different arguments.
`./crclient -u username` for login and `./crclient -l` for logout.
The shell script which I have written is working fine for login but when I'm trying to logout as `./crclient -l` terminal is showing 
    `non-option ARGV-elements: u09me215`.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd Downloads/crclient
if [ $1=="-u" ]
then
./crclient $1 u09me215
else
./crclient $1
fi
```

Now script is running correctly after replacing `if [ $1=="-u" ]` with `if [ $1 = "-u" ]` as @devnull pointed.
But what is difference between "==" and "=" other than one is used for comparisons and other one is used for value assigning. And why `==` was working good for `-u` and not for `-l`.

Comment: Put spaces around `==`.

Comment: @devnull it is working fine for first statement. Getting error after placing spaces.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you need to say: `if [ $1 = "-u" ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without spaces, `$1==-u` is treated as a single string, not a comparison expression. Since a non-empty string always evaluates as true in a `test` command, you end up running

```
./crclient -l u09me215
```

which apparently leads to the error you see.

On a more subtle note, `[ $1 == "-u" ]` is technically not allowed, as the `test` command (as specified by POSIX) does not use `==` for string comparison. However, if your `/bin/sh` is actually `bash`, then `bash` strays a bit from the standard and allows it. You should use either

```
[ "$1" = "-u" ]    # Note the quotes around $1
```

or

```
[[ "$1" == "-u" ]]   # A single = would be fine, and quoting $1 is optional but recommended.
```